# Node.js on via DynDNS

Tags: web-server, node.js, dyndns

I have never used Node.js but since I am developing a browsergame that needs (almost) "realtime" communication, I am planning on using Node.js for this.

To get started, I wanted to use a home server (normal computer) that is conntected to a dynamic IP via DynDNS.

Are there the disadvantages using such a setting?

What is the best way in combination with Node.js to store game status for a online game session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there should not be any disadvantages (for the development phase of your project). But you have to take care that your dynamic IP is not reassigned while your client is online. (e.g. schedule your disconnect at night).

If you have got a low bandwidth connection, take account of the slow data transfer which will  not occur as soon as you are hosting your server professionally.

The most appropriate way to store your game status is:

- **Server side:** Some structured data format, XML or SQL(ite)
- **Client side:** WebSQL. See http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Answer (score 1):

> Are there the disadvantages using such a setting?

Upload bandwidth is generally limited on a home connection, and many ISPs forbid running a server (some going to the point of actively blocking them).

For development, it'll probably be fine, but you won't want to run any sort of active game off that sort of setup.